# Inequality of expansion of $\| \ \ \|$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

The following is from a proof of a paper

`Distributed subgradient Methods for Multi-Agent Optimization, Nedic & Ozdaglar` - Lemma 5

[image]

Note:  $y(k+1)=y(k)-\frac{\alpha}{m}\sum_{j=1}^md_j(k)$

**The picture simply did the expansion of the following:**

$\|y(k+1)-x\|^2=\|(\ \ y(k)-\frac{\alpha}{m}\sum_{j=1}^md_j(k)\ \ ) - x\|^2 = \|(y(k)-x) - \frac{\alpha}{m}\sum_{j=1}^md_j(k)\|^2$

No other specific assumption required.

> My question is the last term of (24), it seems that the author did the following:

$\|\sum_{j=1}^md_j(k)\|^2\leq \sum_{j=1}^m\|d_j(k)\|^2$

I do not think this is correct. (This is not convex function type)

---

Recall:

$\|\|^2$ is a convex function, so  $\|\theta x + (1-\theta)y\|^2\leq \theta\|x\|^2+(1-\theta)\|y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$